# Android : AutoCompleteTextView and TextWatcher

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, textwatcher

I am trying to get the TextWatcher to work with AutoCompleteTextView and facing a bit of an issue. The problem I am facing is that when I start entering the text, I don't get anything in the AutoCompleteTextView if the data input is only one character in length.

Eg. If I enter 1, I should get a list containing 1, 10, 101 etc. However, 1 never shows in the list. What can I do to display suggestions?

```
        final AutocompleteCustomArrayAdapter adapter = new AutocompleteCustomArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.actv, new ArrayList<String>(), null);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);

        textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                 
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `android:completionThreshold` to `1` in your TextView?